# Efficient way to copy unordered String into ordered String

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I'm doing this in Hadoop Java where I'm reading a String. The string is huge that has been tokenized and put in an array.
It has key-value pairs but they are not in any order. I want this order to be rigid so I can load that as a table. So in SQL, if I select a column (after loading this in a table), all the keys of one type should be in colA.

I'm checking each word of the String array and copying them in a new string in a fixed position. The way I thought of doing this is using if else ladder like this:
     //row is the tokenized unordered String

```
 String[] newRow = new String[150];

for (int i = 0; i < row.length; ++i) {

if(row[i].equals("token1")){
                   newRow[0] = row[i]; //key
                   newRow[1] = row[i+1];//value
               }

               else if(row[i].equals("token2")){
                   newRow[2] = row[i];
                   newRow[3] = row[i+1];
               }//...and so on. Elseif ladder at least is at least 100 long.
```

I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way to do this?

PS: I'm not sorting the string. Example: row1 String is {apple,good,banana,bad}, row2 String is {banana,good,apple,bad} where apple and banana are keys. Now in my output I will have two records with say apple as the first key and then banana. So output will be : newRow1: {apple,good,banana,bad} , newRow2: {apple,bad,banana,good}. Essentially I'm rearranging all input to a fixed output.

Comment: So you are sorting an array of `String`s?

Comment: There are many ways that the language in this question is imprecise and that makes it hard to give an answer.

Comment: Why on earth are key/value pairs being stored in a flat array?

Comment: Yes, please clarify your question. What are you trying to achieve? Why are you using a key-value pair for no apparent reason? What do you mean by 'load it as a table'?

Comment: If you post this in the [Code Review forum](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) I promise to help you with this.

Comment: @morgano: I did.
At Others: I hope I clarified the question.

Answer (score 2):

Throw it all away and use a TreeMap. That's what it's for.

Comment: How about HashMap instead? I don't need them sorted.

Comment: `HashMap`'s ordering may not be consistent run to run.  If you want consistency, use `TreeMap`.